# update row in oracle from python timeout/take forever

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using cx_oracle to update record data in oracle from python. It just a simple update, but it takes forever to run and timeout in the end. If I run the same statement directly from Oracle, it works perfectly. Does anyone know why this happened? Thanks!

my code:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect()
cur = con.cursor()
stmt = "UPDATE table SET rank = 4 WHERE id like 'SAP_1000141471' and rank = 2"
cur.execute(stmt)
con.commit()
result =cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Make sure your changes were committed in your Oracle SQL Developer. From experience this usually happens when you have pending commits especially on the same records

Comment: If you are running this in Python, you may be passing values into SQL? Please show this. Also, `LIKE` without a wildcard should be replaced with equality: `=`.

Comment: Also since you are executing an UPDATE, the `fetchall` has nothing to fetch.  Remove that line.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you so much! My terminal runs out successfully with advice from you!

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks! I removed that line. Could you please tell me where should I use fetchall? Thank you!

Comment: @CoffeyLiu see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#fetch-methods